# How to add additional objects with fetch result controller fetched objects list?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I have an entity called “Event“ which has s start and end date properties. I have to show the list of events by grouping them by date in UI. I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch and list the events.

Let's assume an event has start date today and end date tomorrow, here I need to show this event on two different dates in UI but I will have only one entry in the database.

I really don’t want to create multiple entries for an event and also I wish to use fetch result controller as it reduces lot manual calculation. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Use arrays for each day, place event in respective hours interval... This means you will have two "events" in array, despite is just one in your db ,when start hour is "today" and end hour is "tomorrow". Otherwise I don't think you can automatically treat result.

Comment: That is one approach handling it with the array, but I wanted it to solve it using NSFetchedResultsController fetched objects. My app shall keep updating the data in the background so using NSFetchedResultsController will be a very handy solution to refresh the UI. If I don't find then eventually I go with maintaining it in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` does a good job of matching `NSManagedObjects` to indexPaths for a tableView.  However, the mapping is one to one, so any given Event can only appear once in the indexPaths.  To achieve what you want, you would need to create a new entity, say `EventDate`, with a to-many relationship from `Event` to `EventDate`.  Define a string attribute which reflects whether the date is at the start or end of the event.  Then base your FRC on the `EventDate` entity.  Although each EventDate will appear only once, multiple EventDates could relate to a single Event.  The inverse relationship from EventDate to Event will enable you to access the details of a single Event from multiple EventDates.